# DataModelling or ER model building software for MacBook and MYSQL

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard, entity-relationship, data-modeling, mysql-workbench

Hi Friends I have been looking for to build a ER Diagram for my database in Macbook.
Please help me finding a right tool for the same.

I have tried MYSQL Work bench but i need it to be updated dynamically if the DB gets changed.
Also have tried some online stuffs like gliffy.com but of no use.
Please help me I am new to Databases so quick help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get automatic updates (I understand automatic updates as something that happens in the background without any action from you).

MySQL Workbench however has a two-way sync that you can use to update your models at the same time you update your schema (from the model). You can select to do only one direction, but you have to trigger synchronization yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) is a free tool that generates diagrams from a database. It is driven from the commandline. You can generate a new diagram quickly, when your database changes, by re-running your command. Here is an [example diagram](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/images/diagram.png): [image: SchemaCrawler Diagram]

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)